# color palette in seaborn heatmap

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, matplotlib-basemap

When using **LinearSegmentedColormap**, Matplotlib documentation mentions regarding the argument **colors** that

> colors: array-like of colors or array-like of (value, color). If only colors are given, they are equidistantly mapped from the range [0,1]; i.e. 0 maps to colors[0] and 1 maps to colors[-1]. If (value, color) pairs are given, the mapping is from value to color. This can be used to divide the range unevenly.

I have the following colors ['crimson', 'brown', 'lime', 'brown', 'crimson'] and I want to divide the range unevenly in this way:

(-1, -0.5) : 'crimson'

(-0.5, -0.15) : 'brown'

(-0.15, 0.15) : 'lime'

(0.15, 0.5) : 'brown'

(0.5, 1) : 'crimson'

I tried passing the **colors** argument in the format: [(-1, 'crimson'), (-0.5, 'brown), (-0.15, 'lime'), (0.15, 'brown), (0.5, 'crimson')] but got an error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the described color segmentation, you could combine [`LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', colors, len(colors))`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) with a [`BoundaryNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html). Note that you need 6 boundaries for 5 colors.

Working with `(value, color)` pairs for `LinearSegmentedColormap` seems a bit cumbersome, as the values need to normalized to go strictly from 0 to 1. This would be more suited if case you need a continuous range of colors and want to set a specific color at a specific position (not at a specific range).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, BoundaryNorm
import numpy as np

bounds = [-1, -0.5, -0.15, 0.15, 0.5, 1]
colors = ['crimson', 'brown', 'lime', 'brown', 'crimson']
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', colors, N=len(colors))
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=len(colors), )

x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that you can use `plt.colorbar(spacing='proportional')` to display larger chunks of color for the larger ranges. The default is `spacing='uniform'` with equal space for each color.

PS: About the new question, a custom smooth colormap could be created with the `(value, color)` list for `LinearSegmentedColormap` and setting extra boundaries.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

bounds = [-1, -0.5, -0.499, -0.15, -0.149, 0.0, 0.149, 0.15, 0.499, 0.5, 1]
colors = ['crimson', 'crimson', 'brown', 'brown', 'limegreen', 'lime', 'limegreen', 'brown', 'brown', 'crimson', 'crimson']

norm = plt.Normalize(bounds[0], bounds[-1])
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', [(norm(b), c) for b, c in zip(bounds, colors)], N=256)

x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: custom smooth colors]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to make the color darker inside the same color category, in other words, a point with a value of 0.01 will be light lime while a point with 0.14 will be darker lime? Thank you :)